# Insert formula with dynamic row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a formula that looks for a "Date:" Value in column A and pastes a formula in the adjacent B cell, but I can't figure out how to make the formula dynamic.

So if I have a value in A6 and in A8 - I would want the inserted formula to have the same row number T6 and T8. Right now it uses the same row number every time.

```html
Sub Check()
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
  

Set rng = Range("A8:A48")
   
For Each cell In rng
    'test if cell is empty
    If cell.Value = "Date:" Then
        'write to adjacent cell

        cell.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=TEXT(T8,""mmm-dd-yyyy"")&"" | ""&V8&"" - ""&U8&"" | Dept: ""&W8"
       
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the R1C1 style of formatting:

```
Sub Check()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cell As Range 'Remember to declare cell as a range.

    'Qualify your ranges with at least the sheet name.
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A8:A48")

    For Each cell In rng
        'test if cell is empty
        If cell.Value = "Date:" Then
            'write to adjacent cell

            'cell.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=TEXT(T8,""mmm-dd-yyyy"")&"" | ""&V8&"" - ""&U8&"" | Dept: ""&W8"
            cell.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC20,""mmm-dd-yyyy"")&"" | ""&RC22&"" - ""&RC21&"" | Dept: ""&RC23"

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

`RC20` means this row, column 20.  `R1C20` means row 1, column 20.  `RC[-1]` means this row, one column to the left.
http://www.numeritas.co.uk/2013/09/the-%E2%80%98dark-art%E2%80%99-of-r1c1-notation/

Answer (score 2):

You could read in the `.Row` property of the `cell` object and use that in your formula.

Like so:

```
Sub Check()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set rng = Range("A8:A48")

    For Each cell In rng
        'test if cell is empty
        If cell.Value = "Date:" Then
            'write to adjacent cell

            lRow = cell.Row 'Get the current row

            'Use the lRow variable in the formula to create the formula dynamically
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=TEXT(T" & lRow & ",""mmm-dd-yyyy"")&"" | ""&V" & lRow & "&"" - ""&U" & lRow & "&"" | Dept: ""&W" & lRow & ""

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I believe the formula is being set correctly.  A quick test showed that it output a valid formula.  Let me know if anything needs tweaked.

Answer (score 1):

Set a variable for the row value and convert it to a string for your formula insert like so

```
Sub Check()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As String

    'for each row 
    For i = 8 To 48
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "Date:" Then
            'set the string for use in the formula
            j = Trim(Str(i))
            Cells(i, 2).Formula = "=TEXT(T8,""mmm-dd-yyyy"")& "" | "" &V" & j & "& "" - "" &U" & j & "&"" | Dept: ""&W" & j & ""
       End If
    Next
End Sub
```

If your range is really this limited, you would be better of setting a conditional formula directly in your sheet like this:

```
=IF(A8="Date:",TEXT(T8,"mmm-dd-yyyy") & " | " & V8 & " - " & U8 & " | Dept: " & W8,"")
```

This will only display the text on the condition that A8 = Date:. Dragging the formula down will increment the row number